# extract substring from string, python

Tags: python, string

I have a path to some file:

```
'home/user/directory/filename'
```

I want get the `filename`-subpart. The main problem is, I don't know the length of my string and I don't know the length of `filename`-subpart. I know just that filename is placed at the end of a string after the **last** slash `/`. The number of slashes in the string could be absolutely random (because I want get the filename from every directory on some PC).
Consequently I don't see for now the usual method with index extraction, like this:

```
string[number:]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the basename use [os.path.basename](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename):

> Return the base name of pathname path. This is the second element of the pair returned by passing path to the function split()

```
from os import path

pth = 'home/user/directory/filename'
print(path.basename(pth))
filename
```

Or `str.rsplit`:

```
 print(pth.rsplit("/",1)[1])
 filename
```

If you were trying to index a string from the last occurrence you would use rindex:

```
print(pth[pth.rindex("/") + 1:])
```

Comment: Another Small Advice:-  Put that quote in the quote `>` block. It will look bright and clean.

Comment: @BhargavRao,  you are a hard taskmaster ;)

Comment: Just imagine if I become the principal of some college. The students will be !@#$

Comment: @BhargavRao, lol yes, I can still remember  the endearing names we had for some of our teachers.

Answer (score 4):

You could try this also,

```
>>> import os
>>> s = 'home/user/directory/filename'
>>> os.path.split(s)[1]
'filename'
```

Comment: `re.match(r"(.*)/(.*)",s).group(2)`